# Sonata: The service "security.authentication.manager" has a dependency on a non-existent service "security.user.provider.concrete.fos_userbundle"

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-user-bundle

I've correctly setup my Admin bundle in Sonata and followed [the instructions up to 2.5](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/2-2/doc/reference/installation.html#extending-the-bundle).

But upon extending I got the error:

```
ServiceNotFoundException in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php
line 58: The service "security.authentication.manager" has a dependency on
a non-existent service "security.user.provider.concrete.fos_userbundle"."
```

I recall setting up a service for the Admin bundle, but the documentation does not call for such for the User. Is there something I missed, I've double checked to see if I fat fingered it to no prevail.

I've dumped my kernel, composer, security and config to [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/MJ9c9qsM). Seemed like a mouthful to format on here.

**Update:** This is my service dump [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/VAShSvxj)

Once I removed the extra provider from the `security.yaml` file I was able to extend and add the `ApplicationSonataUserBundle`. Now when I visit the `/admin/dashboard` route it says it doesn't exist even though when i run `route:debug` command it shows up on there.

[Here is the github of my project](https://github.com/davideugenepeterson/debugmeplease) and here is the log of the new error I'm having when I login via `/login`: [Prod.log](https://github.com/davideugenepeterson/debugmeplease/blob/5afe84ce4b2013e17cd4bbb1972d747657a43bd2/app/logs/prod.log)

Every time I run `php app/console doctrine:schema:update` i get the error:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
Unknown column type "json" requested. Any Doctrine type that you use has to
be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a list
of all the known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap(). If
this error occurs during database introspection then you might have forgot
to register all database types for a Doctrine Type. Use
AbstractPlatform#registerDoctrineTypeMapping() or have your custom types
implement Type#getMappedDatabaseTypes(). If the type name is empty you might
have a problem with the cache or forgot some mapping information.`
```

Comment: you can see the service using php app/console container:debug ?

Comment: @NawfalSerrar i've updated my question with the service dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Doctrine Exception you must add a new Type Json

> ```
>         types:
>             json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
> ```

mentionned in https://sonata-project.org/bundles/notification/master/doc/reference/installation.html

from `config.yml`

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
```